# I want to use a drop-down menu to select a province from an array in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an array of provinces that I want to be able to select from a drop-down in Google Earth Engine. However, it keeps returning the following error message:
"Items must be a string or an object containing a label and value property."

I want to be able to use the selected province as the boundary for time series graphs later in the function. Does anyone know why I get this error message?

```
//Create filters for each province

var Blekinge = 
     table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Prov_name','Blekinge'));

var Dalarna = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Prov_name','Dalarna'));

var Norrland = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Prov_name','Norrland'));

var Gotland = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Prov_name','Gotland'));

var Medelpad = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Prov_name','Medelpad'));

var Provinces3 = [Blekinge, Dalarna, Norrland, Gotland, Medelpad];


//Province selection

var panel = ui.Panel();

panel.style().set({
width: '400px',
position: 'top-left'
});

Map.add(panel);

//Add drop-down selection for the provinces
var aoi = panel.add(ui.Select({

  items: Provinces3,

}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave you an example on how to do it explaining each step as a comment in the code. If you need more explanation please tell me and I'll try to do it.

```js
// EXAMPLE TABLE
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var name_property = 'country_na'

// Country Names
var all = ee.List(table.toList(table.size()).map(function(feat){return ee.String(ee.Feature(feat).get(name_property))}))
var some = ee.List(['Argentina', 'Chile', 'Uruguay'])

// YOUR TABLE
//var table = ee.FeatureCollection("???")
//var name_property = 'Prov_name'
//var Provinces3 = [Blekinge, Dalarna, Norrland, Gotland, Medelpad]
//var some = ee.List(Provinces3)

// empty panel
var panel = ui.Panel()

var timeSeries = function(feature) {
  // Your code for time series graph..
  var name = ee.String(feature.get(name_property)).getInfo()
  print('I am plotting a time series for '+name)
}


// Main function
var addFeat = function(name, fc, property) {
  // Filter Feature by its name
  var filtered = fc.filterMetadata(property, 'equals', name)
  var feature = ee.Feature(filtered.first())

  // Apply time series code..
  timeSeries(feature)

  // Add Layer to Map
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(feature, {}, name)
  var layers = Map.layers()
  layers.set(0, layer)
  Map.centerObject(feature)
}

// Callback for dropdown menu
var callback = function(name) {
  addFeat(name, table, name_property)
}

// Define dropdown
var drop = ui.Select({
  items: some.getInfo(),
  //items: all.getInfo(),
  onChange: callback
})

// Adds
panel.add(drop)
Map.add(panel)
```

Try it here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d8967ff35492177d824955ba034267b6

Comment: This code works for what you describe and I very much appreciate the effort, however what I should have told you earlier is that each province also has smaller districts, so the end result is a drop-down menu containing several of the same province (as many as there are districts).

Comment: How will you know which one is the one you want?

Comment: A mean of the districts contained within the province, to create a boundary selection for the province as a whole. Then the drop-down would contain a single value for each province that is representative.

Comment: I think I can accomplish that with a dissolve, no worries.